# How can I tell if I'm running properly

Tags: running, technique

I have about 6 months running regularly, about 1–2 times per week. Today I ran 14 km (about 8 miles) — a milestone for me!

I feel great and I don't want to stop, but I don't know if I'm doing properly or not.  I don't want to get injured or something just for not asking.

How can I tell if my running technique is correct?

Comment: I think a visit to a personal trainer/physical therapist/maybe even a doctor would tell you a lot more than people on the Internet.

Comment: This seems like it should be in "Fitness and Nutrition", not sports. If not, the above answers are a good start. Barefoot or as close to it as you can get is all the rage, and is legitimate advice.

Comment: I've also found this video which shows 3 tips to run properly ( or better ) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tx6x2cD6Y8Q

Answer (score 17):

[Chris McDougal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_McDougall), author of Born to Run, a book that will make you want to go run immediately and properly,

> “Imagine your kid is running into the street and you have to sprint
>   after her in bare feet.  You’d automatically lock into perfect form —
>   you’d be up on your forefeet, with your back erect, head steady, arms
>   high, elbows driving, and feet touching down quickly on the forefoot
>   and kicking back toward your butt.”

And further, I hope [this](http://nerdfitness.com/blog/2011/08/22/running-properly/) article will give lots of knowledge about **running properly**.

Answer (score 13):

First of all congratulations with your milestone! It feels great to be running.

If you have 6 months of running in your legs now, you probably don't have the worst technique, because then you would have been injured already :=)

If you haven't done so much running in your life before, and never played any sports like football, I think I would have focused on other things before landing on your forefoot. 
Focus rather on landing your feet at the center of your gravity and running relaxed with a slightly lean-forward angle. (Over focusing on forefeet landing almost killed my legs)

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oN1x3Ik1t5Y&feature=related) is a good video of a guy who improves his technique.

The most important thing is that you don't skip your running exercises, regardless of technique!

Answer (score 3):

People often forget that running correctly, is actually quite hard. Most people that ran a lot during childhood, get it more or less right, but if your the type that never really has run a lot, some instruction can be very helpful.

Internet guides, articles and so on, are good, but I would probably look to your local atletic club where they have competition +800 meter runners and get some lessons there.

You don't have to join the club, but get 3-4 lessons, come back in some months and get some follow-up lessons.

Answer (score 2):

A very good video that explains in detail a good posture in running: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tx6x2cD6Y8Q. I used it myself to improve my technique.

You'll find in there all the key elements.

Of course, if you go for trail running, things complicate a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

Responding to several of the answers here: running barefoot may be a fad - and may even work for some minority of the population - but one should be careful and informed if inclined to attempt it.   Careful studies have shown downsides to running barefoot in terms of sacrificing speed/performance and distribution of stress on the foot.

An alternative may be to wear rather minimalistic shoes. How minimalistic you may go would be very specific to you/your feet.  Consider that having slightly more weight but having the support you really need will go a long way towards avoiding injuries.

As far as your form: it would make sense to be evaluated by a running coach.  They can give you tips on areas you might be able to tweak.